# Will 2009 tutorial code be compatible with current version of Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

I'm want to learn how to create a simple **CRUD** using **Code Igniter**.

**[This tutorial](http://henrihnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/simple-crud-application/)** is exactly what I need, but it was posted in **2009**.

Will all of this tutorial code be compatible with the latest **Code Igniter** version?

Comment: Not used Code Igniter before, but my most "original" response of the day is..... try it and see.

Comment: try http://www.grocerycrud.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, yes (by a rapid skimming of the code you posted).

One important thing is that now the main CI Classes are prefixed with CI_, so your controllers would extends **CI_Controller**, and your models **CI_Model**.

Some DB methods changed their names, so what once were getWhere() became get_where() (IIRC), and there's has been a big change in dropping support for PHP4 (constructors are now being used with the __construct() method, for ex.), even if PHP 5 is not embraced totally (no namespaces, for example)

Anyway, you can find a comprehensive list of changes since that version (should be the 1.7.x I believe) in the [changelog](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html), you can work out any error you might get just by looking at what has been removed, added or renamed.